# Axios response doesn't get executed properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, axios

I have the following code,

```
function FileUpload(props) {

const [Images, setImages] = useState([])

const onDrop = (files) => {

    let formData = new FormData();
    const config = {
        header: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }
    formData.append("file", files[0])
    //save the Image we chose inside the Node Server 
    Axios.post('/api/product/uploadImage', formData, config)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.data.success) {

                setImages([...Images, response.data.image])
                props.refreshFunction([...Images, response.data.image])

            } else {
                alert('Failed to save the Image in Server')
            }
        })
}
```

However whenever I try calling the axios call and try using my image uploader, I always the unsuccessful message of "Failed to save the Image in server"

Here is where the API call leads to:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`)
},
fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname)
    if (ext !== '.jpg' || ext !== '.png') {
        return cb(res.status(400).end('only jpg, png are allowed'), false);
    }
    cb(null, true)
}
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file")


//=================================
//             Product
//=================================

router.post("/uploadImage", auth, (req, res) => {

upload(req, res, err => {
    if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, err })
    }
    return res.json({ success: true, image: res.req.file.path, fileName:
    res.req.file.filename })
})

});
```

Can someone help me out with why the image is not being uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many reasons.The code looks fine to me

- First one as you expect a single image file path from the server.You can set it directly

  setImages(response.data.image)
- Second have you made the uploads folder since the image is saved there by your node server
- Third the file extensions must be these `ext !== '.jpg' || ext !== '.png'`

Comment: Thank you! Really stupid of me I forgot to create the uploads folder in the first place :(

Comment: Thanks Pleasure of mine